# findspark.init() list index out of range error

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

When using findspark.find() I am given the path that spark is installed in, but when trying findspark.init(path) I am getting a list index out of range error using jupyter notebook

I have made sure my SPARK_HOME and PATH variables are correctly set as well

> *below code outputs spark home path*

```
import findspark
findspark.find()
```

> *initializing with output of above spark home path*

```
import findspark
findspark.init(path)
```

> *throws list index out of range error*

```
    133     # add pyspark to sys.path
    134     spark_python = os.path.join(spark_home, 'python')
--> 135     py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, 'lib', 'py4j-*.zip'))[0]
    136     sys.path[:0] = [spark_python, py4j]
    137 

    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I dont understand how it can output the correct path, but is unable to initialize spark

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by moving my Spark and Hadoop directories to my C drive where anaconda and jupyter are installed. Then updating the SPARK_HOME and PATH environment variables to reflect the new destinations.

After committing the above changes and restarting my terminal I was able to connect to spark via jupyter notebook and execute code.